# php – How to get POST and GET variables with CROSS-DOMAIN Ajax/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I have a problem with cross-domain requests with Jquery and PHP.

That's code I have in frontend side:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var params = {};
    params['phone'] = "123";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType : "jsonp",
        jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
        url: "http://tennisterin.com/api/booking/user",
        data: params,
        error: function( xhr, textStatus ) {
          alert( [ xhr.status, textStatus ] );
        },
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);  
        }
    });

});
```

That's what I have on server (php) side:

```
if (isset($_GET['phone'])) { $phone = inCode($_GET['phone']); } else { $phone = ""; }
echo $phone; //always empty
```

Everything fine with local requests but "phone" is always empty when request made from cross-domain location.

Why is there a problem? How to fix it? Any ideas?

Thanks!

P.S.
I found the narrow place of the code:
Everything works fine when I use

```
url: "http://tennisterin.com/api.php?page=booking&subpage=user",
```

instead of

```
url: "http://tennisterin.com/api/booking/user",
```

But I have working rule in my .htaccess for this case:

```
RewriteRule ^api/booking/user?$ api.php?page=booking&subpage=user [L]
```

So it should work both sides!
I see the problem only with cross-domain requests. How cross-domain and .htaccess are connected?

Comment: How can you tell `phone` is empty? What are you doing to inspect the response?

Comment: For test purposes I return everything from php back as a result of ajax request. It returns text, any symbols but not variables I have sent.

Comment: what is `inCode($_GET['phone'])` ?  If the Get variable "phone" is set then why not just echo it? or.. perhaps do `print_r($_GET)` and see what comes?

Comment: It's inner function. It works fine – I have just removed it, wrote print_r($_GET['phone']) but it shows the same empty result.

Comment: Try making the request synchronous as a test. It's supposed to always be Async, but for a few minutes try it out?